# How to make some of the text in a cell bold?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I make the words before " - " bold?

[image: Image of spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. As you are new, please, check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

About your question, try something like this:

```
Sub MAKE_IT_BOLD(ByVal ThisRange As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Dim Pos As Integer

For Each Rng In ThisRange
    Pos = InStr(1, Rng.Value, "-", vbTextCompare) - 1
    If Pos > 0 Then Rng.Characters(1, Pos).Font.Bold = True
Next Rng

End Sub
```

This sub will check every cell in `ThisRange` and will find the position of the first `-` in string. If that position is found, then it will make bold all characters from 1 to the position of `-`.

I hope you can adapt this code to your needs.

Comment: Appreciate this! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad to help, @JohnAinge . Please, if this answer solved your problem, mark it as correct, so the question will be closed :)